# How to use REGEXEXTRACT only on rows that contain a cell which contain a string within a SUM?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, sum, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

If my data set is:

```
|                  H              |   U  |   |   |   |
| 100 Main St, Berkeley, CA       | $200 |   |   |   |
| 200 Other St, San Francisco, CA | $400 |   |   |   |
| 300 This St, Oakland, CA        | $250 |   |   |   |
| 111 That St, San Francisco, CA  | $90  |   |   |   |
```

How would I get the total sum of all values in column D, for rows which contain the word "San Francisco"?  This dataset is on Sheet1, while my formula is on Sheet2
Currently, I use this formula, to sum up all rows, regardless of their city.

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(iferror(REGEXEXTRACT(Sheet1!U2:U918&".","\$?([0-9]+)[.,]")*1)))
```

But I tried using SUMIF, and Regexmatch as the first argument to ArrayFormula and neither of those worked.

UPDATE:

player0 gave me the answer(I added a sum around it to get it exactly to output what I want).

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({Onfleet!H2:H, REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(Onfleet!U2:U), "\d+")*1}, "select sum(Col2) where lower(Col1) contains 'oakland' group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''")))
```

Comment: You show your numbers as being in D and addresses in C ,but your formula looks like it's attempting to use column U.
Maybe you could share a quick sample to make it more clear where things are?

Comment: Sorry, I'll correct it.  I created dummy data by hand and forgot to change those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({Sheet1!H2:H, REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(Sheet1!U2:U), "\d+")*1}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where lower(Col1) contains 'san francisco' 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col2)''"))
```

[image]

Comment: I need to run a REGEXEXTRACT on column U, because it contains more than the sales total, and I need to ignore the rest of the text in that cell.  I've updated the question to show that.

Comment: I'm getting a "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined" error.

Comment: It's now giving me a "Error
Query completed with an empty output."

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Sure, I had to remove some personal information, but here's a link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q1mStehaY5Wm3gR3413yhmFTg55vserlJT_kiWFcIYw/edit?usp=sharing

I am trying to use this formula in the second sheet "Sales".

Comment: here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mO9nLAYaFWriZqEy4ZB6V-z8Avz0-DXAnIL_gaCbwtg/edit#gid=235320702

Comment: your example dataset does not have san francisco thats why you got empty results from query

Comment: Okay, that seems close, but how do I get it so it doesn't display the addresses?
I just need the cell to have the value "135", the total of the three sales in Berkeley.

Comment: I figured out the exact formula, I just wrapped the ARRAYFORMULA in a SUM, and remove the Col1 from the select.